# Check if react-router path is active

Tags: reactjs, react-router

How to check if generic react-router path matches current location pathname?

```
react-router path: /Movies/:id
location.pathname: /Movies/56fa7446bae6eb301e5937f3
```

I want to use route paths with menu buttons, to set class="active".

EDIT:

To clarify, paths in my app look like:

```
/Movies/56fa7/watch
```

and not like:

```
/Movies/watch/56fa7
```

How do I check if the former route is active?

Is it doable without `<Link>` component?

`/Movies/56fa7/watch` is arbitrary after `/Movies`, and `<Link>` obviously can't be pointed to an arbitrary location. So let's ignore `<Link>` for a moment:

Is there a standalone function or property in react-router that checks if `/Movies/:id/watch` is active?

Comment: Check: https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/tree/master/examples/active-links

Comment: It won't work, because you can't set <Link to={/Movies/:id} />.
And <Link to={/Movies} /> won't be active when pathname is /Movies/56fa7446bae6eb301e5937f3.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/matchPath), you could use [**`matchPath`**](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/modules/matchPath.js) function which takes two arguments:

1. **pathname** you want to match (`String`).
2. **options** (`Object`) or path (`String`) to match against.

If matched it will return an object of this shape:

```js
{
  path, // the path used to match
  url, // the matched portion of the URL
  isExact, // whether or not we matched exactly
  params
}
```

Otherwise you'll get `null`.

To make use of it in your components you could simply do:

```js
import { matchPath } from 'react-router';

// ...

render () {
  const isMovieWatchPathActive = !!matchPath(
    this.props.location.pathname, 
    '/Movies/:id/watch'
  ); 

  // ...
}
```

Hope it'll help someone.

Comment: It did, thank you. The only edit is that you should import `matchPath` from `react-router`

Comment: That worked for me - thank you.

One thing that this also works

document.location.pathname 

instead of 

this.props.location.pathname,

Answer (score 5):

#### As of React Router v4 (March 2017):

I'm a bit late to the party, but hopefully this will help anyone with the same question. When a component is rendered through a `Route`, certain props are passed to it. These props can be used to determine which route is active.

In a component rendered by a `Route`, you can use `this.props.match.url` to get the actual URL requested by the browser, and you can use `this.props.match.path` to get the path pattern for the current route.

Check working example here: https://codesandbox.io/s/20o7q0483j

Docs related to this are available here:
https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/Route-props

Comment: The `match` object is not available when using the `useParams` Hook

Answer (score 5):

use this

```
import { matchPath } from "react-router";

const match = matchPath("/users/123", {
  path: "/users/:id",
  exact: true,
  strict: false
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out the Link's property: activeStyle or activeClassName. They are supposed to automatically set the link to active when route matches. See the example: https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-tutorial/tree/master/lessons/05-active-links

Comment: Yes, but they will only match exact pathnames. I need solution for general paths used in <Route> components.

Comment: I see, although when child matches, the parent should be active also. https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-tutorial/tree/master/lessons/07-more-nesting

Comment: See EDIT in the original question.

Comment: This has changed in v4, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/43081982/2333665

Answer (score 0):

**React Router V6**

*MatchPath* in V6 is different from the other version, below is an example of how to use it.

```
publicRoutes.forEach(({ path }) => {
      if (!!matchPath(path, location.pathname)) {
         ...
      }
    });
```

Below is the link to matchPath documentation and link to another stackoverflow post with more details, hope this helps! :)

- https://reactrouter.com/en/6.14.2/utils/match-path
- [React-Router V6 check if path matches a pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61235191/react-router-v6-check-if-path-matches-a-pattern)