# React-Router V6 check if path matches a pattern

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm trying to check a "/admin/posts/new" to "/admin/*" in react-router v6. I found that there is a matchRoutes function

```
import { useLocation } from "react-router";
const { pathname } = useLocation();
const isAdminPath = someMatchFunc(pathname,"/admin/*") <<<< something goes here returns true or null
```

Answer (score 16):

You should be able to use the matchPath function. It would look something like this in v6:

```
import { useLocation, matchPath } from "react-router";
const { pathname } = useLocation();
const isAdminPath = matchPath("/admin/*", pathname);
```

It's important to note that they changed the parameters in v6. In v5, you would have done something like this instead.

```
import { useLocation, matchPath } from "react-router";
const { pathname } = useLocation();
const isAdminPath = matchPath(pathname, { path: "/admin", exact: false });
```

Comment: But matchPath is not considering the basename. what we need to add inorder to match the path along with basename.

Comment: @MonishN - The original question didn't say anything about needing to match basename.

Answer (score -1):

Use `useRouteMatch` instead `matchPath`

```
import { useRouteMatch } from "react-router-dom";

function BlogPost() {
  let match = useRouteMatch("/blog/:slug");

  // Do whatever you want with the match...
  return <div />;
}
```

Comment: If you need to see if child routes are there, you can use `*` e.g. `let match = useRouteMatch("/blog/:slug/*")` which would return `match.params['*']` as a string of anything matching. For example `/blog/hello/edit` would be `{ slug: 'hello', '*': 'edit' }`.

Comment: This only works for react router v5 as `useRouteMatch` isn't exported in v6.